# Beamer: How to hide top-bar when there is no slide title (and on the main title page)?

Tags: beamer

In Beamer, Latex adds a (blank) bar at the top of the slide even when there is no title.

```latex
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\title {Test}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Test\\\vfill
Test\\\vfill
Test\\\vfill
Test\\\vfill
Test\\\vfill
Test\\\vfill
Test
\par\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How does one omit this bar and start slides with no title at the top of the page? (similarly for the presentation title page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the argument `[plain]` to the frame command:

```latex
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\title {Test}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[plain]
Test\\\vfill
Test\\\vfill
Test\\\vfill
Test\\\vfill
Test\\\vfill
Test\\\vfill
Test
\par\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a picture of the output.